# Permutation problem - probability bound

Tags: probability

I have a similar question as this [Random permutation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140749/random-permutation-problem), where 
  X
  :=
  the number of inversions in 
  π
.

But I need to find an upper bound on the probability that X is more than (1+epsilon)E[X],epsilon > 0. Is this similar with applying directly Chebychev's Inequality, or another technique must be used ? Considering that k parameter now is depending on E[X] rather being a constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chebyshev's inequality. It's not a problem that $k$ is related to $E[X]$, because  $E[X]$ is a number, not a random variable.

Writing Chebyshev's inequality as $P(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\le k^{-2}$, we see that $k=\epsilon\,\sigma^{-1} \mu$, which bounds the probability by $\epsilon^{-2}\sigma^2\mu^{-2}$.

If your $\epsilon$ is small, the estimate will be poor, and you may have to abandon Chebyshev's inequality in favor of another approach, specific to the distribution of $X$.