# Probability: The Variance of pair swaps in permutation

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, variance

im trying to solve the following question:

let σ∈Sn be a random permution of {1,2,.....,n} as Sn is the set of all permutions with n variables
and let f(σ) be a random variable that counts the pairs swap in permutions

for example {1,2,3} -> {2,1,3} as 1 and 2 swapped.

as for E[f] i splitted f into nC2 random variables that indicates if a pair swapped
and as result i got that E[f] = $\frac{1}{2}$

now im trying to solve Var[f]

as i tried to use Var[f] = E[$f^2$] - $(E[f])^2$ = E[$f^2$] - $\frac{1}{4}$

but i cant figure out how to calculate E[$f^2$]
and how to check exactly that i got the right answer in the end.
I would truly appreciate any help on computing this variance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: By "swaps" do you mean [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics))? Shouldn't you get $\Bbb E[f]=\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140805/1174161

Comment: from the definition of inversions i think its aint the same

Comment: If not inversions, then do you mean the minimum number of transpositions used to represent a permutation as a product of transpositions, or do you mean the number of $2$-cycles? Together with inversions, these are the three interpretations of your question I can think of.

Comment: yeah sorry for the wrong definition but as i see 2-cycles is the right definition for what im looking for im looking to calculate the variance of 2 cycles count in permutions